# I keep getting Error: Cannot find module './config.json/'

Tags: javascript, windows, discord.js

I am getting this error that from my knowledge, means that it cannot find the file `config.json` but when I type the file location directly into the terminal, it opens the file straight away.

This is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\10730\Downloads\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler> node .
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './config.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\10730\Downloads\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler\commands\ticket\ticket.js
- C:\Users\10730\Downloads\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler\handlers\command.js
- C:\Users\10730\Downloads\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\10730\Downloads\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler\commands\ticket\ticket.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\10730\\Downloads\\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler\\commands\\ticket\\ticket.js',
    'C:\\Users\\10730\\Downloads\\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler\\handlers\\command.js',
    'C:\\Users\\10730\\Downloads\\discord.js-tutorials-recon-handler\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get this code to work for a Discord bot using discord.js

Thankyou all so much for the help, didn't expect this many people to help me out. :)

[Folder Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBEK8.png)

Comment: Hi Wocsa. Could you share some code, its pretty much impossible to help you without an example

Comment: Can we also see your folder tree

Comment: This is the index.js file that is mentioned at the bottom of the error. (Split because reply limit isn't big enough.
First half:

Comment: ```const {Collection, Client, Discord} = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')
const client = new Client({
    disableEveryone: true
})
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const config = require('./config.json/')
const prefix = config.prefix
const token = config.token
client.ticketCatergory = '833660991690637372'
client.commands = new Collection();
client.aliases = new Collection();
client.categories = fs.readdirSync("./commands/");
["command"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);```

Comment: Did you install `node_module`?

Comment: it looks like it want to access an directory named ` ./config.json/` and if you use this directory syntax, it will search in this directory an `index.js`. for me it seems, there is just an `/` too much

Comment: }); 
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}help`)
    console.log(`${client.user.username} ✅`)
})

Comment: Consider editing your post and adding this code in the question itself.

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question with the code example. :)

Comment: @AlenVlahovljak I ran `npm i discord.js`

Comment: Try removing the `/` at the end of the file name `./config.json/` and update it to `./config.json`.

Answer (score 1):

There is one `/` too much. Remove that and it should work:

```
const config = require('./config.json')
```

Comment: I have updated the error in the question.

Comment: Can you add your folder tree to the question as well?

Comment: Just added it :)

Comment: And in which file are you calling `const config = require('./config.json')`?

Comment: It is in index.js but `const config = require('./config.json')` is also in ticket.js :)

Comment: If you want to call it in your `ticket.js` you have to add a `.` => `const config = require('../config.json')`

Comment: I'll take a closer look later. But for the future development of your bot I'd recommend using [environment variables](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786). In my opinion this is a lot easier :)

Comment: @Wosca Does your problem still exist?